# grails spring security custom userDetailsService

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have a problem injecting my userDetailsService into my custom provider. I have a custom userDetailsService which I'm trying to inject to my provider, however, for some reason from my provider this resolves in a null userDetailsService.
The following is from my resources.groovy:

```
beans = {
  userDetailsService(CustomUserDetailsService) {
  }

  stupidAuthenticationProvider(StupidAuthenticationProvider) {
    userDetailsService = ref("userDetailsService")
  }
}
```

Basically I'm just defining it in my provider as follows:

```
public class StupidAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
def userDetailsService
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Looking in the beans defined by [Spring Security Core](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy) this seems to be the correct name. Are you sure that you declared `userDetailsService`? In your bootstrap, if you print `grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('userDetailsService')` the instance is `CustomUserDetailsService`?

Comment: yes: com.test.CustomUserDetailsService@6180ef93

Comment: How are you using stupidAuthenticationProvider?

Comment: basically i have just added the provider to the springsecurity.providerNames...
grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = ['stupidAuthenticationProvider']

This goes well and when i try to log in this provider is triggered.
Once inside the stupidAuthenticationProvider i have defined the userDetailsService as : def userDetailsService, but this is resolved as null, just println userDetailsService or trying to invoke some method resolvs as null

Comment: the problem is just that the userDetailsService seems not to be injected properly

Comment: even def grailsApplication   also resolves to null from within the provider? Are they not resolvable from within this context ?

Comment: `grailsApplication` will be null if you're not explicitly injecting it.  You could try enabling autowiring for your provider: `stupidAuthenticationProvider(StupidAuthenticationProvider) { bean -> bean.autowire = "byName" }`

Comment: RESOLVED:It was my mistake all along, i had a duplicate definition of the StupidAuthenticationProvider. One of them was missing the userDetailsService hence setting it to null. My mistake...All your answers were correct.Thanks for all your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the qualified name of the classes:

```
    beans = {
        userDetailsService(com.test.CustomUserDetailsService){
        }

        StupidAuthenticationProvider(com.test.XXX.StupidAuthenticationProvider) {
            userDetailsService = ref('userDetailsService ')
        }
    }
```

Comment: this did not change anything

Answer (score 2):

Is your CustomUserDetailsService in a package? If yes, then you should give it's fully qualified name in the config.

The following is working for me:

```
beans = {
    userDetailsService(com.mysite.MyUserDetailsService)
//and then refer it like...
    emailAuthenticationProvider(com.mysite.EmailAuthenticationProvider) {
        springSecurityService = ref('springSecurityService')
        userDetailsService = ref('userDetailsService')
    }
}
```

and in the auth provider...

```
class EmailAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    def userDetailsService
    def springSecurityService

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a userDetailsService without the fully qualified name and it works well.

Comment: In the beans DSL the parameter in the parentheses is a `java.lang.Class` object - you can either use the fully qualified name `userDetailsService(com.mysite.MyUserDetailsService)` or use just the plain name `userDetailsService(MyUserDetailsService)` _and also_ add a suitable `import com.mysite.*` to the top of the file.  Both variants are equivalent.